# How to troubleshoot and reduce communication overhead on Rockwell ControlLogix

Tags: ethernet, plc

Need help. We have a plc that's cpu keeps getting maxed out. We've already upgraded it once. Now we need work on optimize it.

We have over 50 outgoing msg instructions, 60 incoming, and 103 number of ethernet devices (flow meters, drives, etc) I've gone through and tried to make sure everything is cached that can be, only instructions that are currently needed are running, and communication to the same plc happen in the same scan, but I haven't made a dent.

I'm having trouble identifying which instructions are significant. It seems the connections will be consolidated so lots of msgs shouldn't be too big of a problem. Considering Produced & Consumed tags but our team isn't very familiar with them and I believe you have to do a download to modify them, which is a problem. Our IO module RPIs are all set to around 200ms, but that didn't seem to make a difference (from 5ms).

We have a shutdown this weekend and I plan on disabling everything and turning it back on one part at a time to see where the load is really coming from.

Does anyone have any suggestions? The task monitor doesn't have a lot of detail that I can understand, i.e. It's either too summarized or too instant for me to make heads or tales of it. Here is a [couple screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZS3a.jpg) from the Task Monitor  to shed some light on what I'm seeing.

Comment: did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: No. I'm convinced something was fundamentally wrong with that PLC and it should have been rebuilt. None of the metrics made sense. After disabling all code, the IO was still taking all the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

First question coming to mind is are you using the Continues Task or is all in Periodic tasks?

Comment: Periodic. Set to about 400 ms, but only taking about 150. We were increasing it to help give more time for communication but now it does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: In Controller Settings -> Advanced, how is overhead allocated? To communications or the continues task?

Comment: By the way. If your team is capable of setting up 110 msg instructions you should be more than capable of using produced/consumed tags. The produced/consumed tags is basicly the same as CIP communication using msg instructions just without all the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue many years ago with a CLX. Rockwell suggested increasing the System Overhead Time Slice to around 40 to 50%. The default is 20%.

Some details:
Look at the System Overhead Time Slice (go to Advanced tab under Controller Properties). Default is 20%. This determines the time the controller spends running its background tasks (communications, messaging, ASCII) relative to running your continuous task.

From Rockwell:
For example, at 25%, your continuous task accrues 3 ms of run time. Then the background tasks can accrue up to 1 ms of run time, then the cycle repeats. Note that the allotted time is interrupted, but not reduced, by higher priority tasks (motion, user periodic or event tasks).

Here is a detailed Word Doc from Rockwell:
https://rockwellautomation.custhelp.com/ci/fattach/get/162759/&ved=2ahUKEwiy88qq0IjeAhUO3lQKHf01DYcQFjADegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw125pgiSor_bf-BpNSvNVF8

And here is a detailed KB from Rockwell:
https://rockwellautomation.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/42964

Comment: One more thing, I agree with Claus. If your able to make offline changes and download to the PLC you will be better off using producer/consumer tags as apposed to 110 message statements.